# Geospatial data in R: I have a matrix of latitudes, a matrix of longitudes, and a matrix of values-how combine?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, netcdf

I have three matrices: the first one is a matrix of longitude points, the second is a matrix of latitude points, and the third is a matrix of air quality values, measured at each latitude and longitude. In R, I would like to combine all of these into a raster. Following the discussion [here](http://%20http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/week04-netCDF.html), and using the madeup data below, I thought I would be able to combine the matrices in this way:

```
mat.lat=matrix(rep(41:50,10),10)
mat.long=matrix(rep(91:100,10),10)
mat.aq=matrix(rnorm(100),10)

r=raster(mat.aq,
    xmn=min(mat.long),
    xmx=max(mat.long),
    ymn=min(mat.lat),
    ymx=max(mat.lat)
)
```

However, when I plot the data, they are a little bit *off*. I suspect it's because my data is actually more complicated than the one in the madeup data, and the actual latitude and longitude grid aren't evenly spaced, and evenly spaced is what the raster command expects.

But I feel like there has to be a smarter way to combine the matrices than just plowing along the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude values. I actually have the values of the lat/lon, so I don't want to interpolate them. But after a lot of searching, I can't figure out how. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839891/r-combining-a-separate-data-frame-of-longitude-and-one-of-latitude-into-spatial) question came close, the poster found a solution to their problem that doesn't solve mine.

**How do you layer together an two matrices of latitudes and longitudes with a matrix of data points into a raster (or other spatial data frame)?**

For background, I received two netcdf files from a colleague: one with a grid of latitude and longitude points that cover our area of interest. In this first netcdf file, the latitude and longitude are variables, not dimensions. The second netcdf file contains the data we're interested in, but no latitude or longitude. I would like to map the data in these files in R, but the standard functions for reading on netcdf files assume that the dimension of the netcdf file has the latitude and longitude already.
Following the discussion [here](http://%20http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/week04-netCDF.html), I figured that I could extract the three arrays of information, and layer them back together, but I'm having a tough time doing that.
**REVISION**
I found a way to do it, although I'm sure it's a horribly, embarrassingly inefficient way to skin the cat, I share in case someone else google-stumbles onto this page.

```
pts=cbind(lon=as.vector(mat.lon),
        lat=as.vector(mat.lat),
        aq=as.vector(mat.aq))
    inter1=data.frame(pts)
    inter1 <- cbind(inter1, 
        cat = rep(1L, nrow(inter1)),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    #convert to spatial points
    coordinates(inter1) = ~lon + lat
    proj4string(inter1)<-CRS("+init=epsg:4269")

    r.grid <- raster(inter1,crs=CRS("+init=epsg:4269"),
        nrows=315,
        ncols=288)
    r=rasterize(x=pts[,1:2],y=r,field=pts[,3])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with using the dimensions that *are* provided. Presumably coordinates in a different spatial reference system? Once you have these as a raster, you can use `projectRaster` to transform to lon/lat.

If the data are not on a regular grid, treat the data as points. You could do this

```
mlat=matrix(rep(41:50,10),10)
mlong=matrix(rep(91:100,10),10, byrow=TRUE)
maq=matrix(rnorm(100),10)

pts <- cbind(lat=as.vector(mlat), lon=as.vector(mlong), aq=as.vector(maq))
```

If the data were on a regular grid (as they are in the example data), you could do

```
library(raster)
r <- rasterFromXYZ(pts)
plot(r)
```

If they are not, and you do want them on a regular grid, you need interpolate. See ?raster::interpolate

Comment: Thank you. I can make it work (happily) on the example data, but not on the actual data. The actual data is a grid that's 315x288 (90,720 cells). I can create the pts data frame, but the rasterFromXYZ of that data frame ran for an hour without finishing. When I canceled it's run, I had more than 50 errors about data size
`In writeBin(v, x@file@con, size = x@file@dsize) :
  problem writing to connection`

I suspect that I'm somehow telling R to do way more complicated things than I really want from it, but I'm not sure where

Comment: `> dim(lon)`
`[1] 315 288`
`> dim(lat)`
`[1] 315 288`
`> dim(aq1)`
`[1] 315 288`
`> pts=cbind(lon=as.vector(lon),lat=as.vector(lat),aq=as.vector(aq1))`
`> r=rasterFromXYZ(pts,crs=CRS(epsg.txt))`

It stalled out for more than an hour and a half here.

Comment: I am guessing that the function found a regular grid on which these points fall; but that it it is has an extremely high resolution. That should not happen and I should look into that.